# Prove that $k(u,v) = f(k_1(u,v))$ is a valid kernel, where $f$ is a polynomial with positive coefficients

Tags: matrices, polynomials

> I want to show that $k(u, v) = f(k1(u, v))$, is a valid kernel where $f$ is a polynomial with positive coefficients.

**Proof.**
Since each polynomial term is a product of kernels with a positive coefficient, the proof follows by applying (1) and (2).

(1) $k(u,v) = \alpha k_a(u,v) + \beta k_b(u,v)$, where for any choice of $\alpha,\beta \geq 0$, $k$is a valid kernel.

(2)$k(u,v) = k_1(u,v)k_2(u,v)$ is a valid kernel.

I think this is really simple, but I'm having a hard time understanding the proof. It isn't clear to me with each polynomial term is a product of kernel.

Comment: are you sure you typed (1) correctly?

Comment: no. but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

A polinomial of degree $n$ can be written as follows:

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$$

> **Claim:** For ever $n$, and every $a_i\geq 0$, if $k$ is a valid kernel, so is 
>       $f(k)$, provided the conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ given in the question.

Applying the second condition iteratively, one can see that if $k$ is a valid kernel, $k^i$ is also a valid kernel for all $i>0$.

Next, consider the first condition assume that $\beta=0$. Hence, $y_i=a_i k^i$ is also a valid kernel for all $i$. As a result,

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$$

is a sum of valid kernels. This sum can be written as $n$ pairwise sums of the terms $a_i x^i$. For example let $n=3$, then

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^3 a_i x^i=a_0+a_1 x+ a_2x^2+a_3x^3=(((a_0+a_1 x)+ a_2x^2)+a_3x^3)$$

the results of the sum of every paranthesis is a valid sum by the first condition and since $a_i x^i$ is a valid kernel as shown above. Hence the whole sum is also a valid kernel.

Note that if $a_0\neq 0$ one needs an extra condition that $$k(u,v)=k_1(u,v)+a_0\quad a_0\geq 0\quad\mbox{is a valid kernel}$$

Comment: what does $k^i$ refer to?

Comment: $k(u,v)^i$, where $i$ is a non-negative integer.

Comment: What is $k^i$ relationship to $k$?

Comment: I'm probably going to need to ask a lot of questions because I'm really not getting this answer.

Comment: As a result $f(x) = \sum a_ix^i$ is a sum of valid kernels. I don't follow the reasoning. As a result of what? And why?

Comment: And what is $x^i$? Is it the $ith$ position in the polynomial?

Comment: if $k_3=k_1*k_2$ is a valid kernel, then $k_4=k_3*k_1$ is also valid, for example: then $k_4=k_3*k_1=k_1^2*k_2$ is also valid, usw. in this way we can create any power of $k$ and it is still a valid kernel.

Comment: Why are we assuming that $\beta$ = 0?

Comment: no $i$th power of the variable $x$.

Comment: @lars please think before you ask a question and read the answer more than once if you dont get it. why $\beta=0$ because we can! look at the definition of $\beta$. It can be chosen equal to $0$ right?

Comment: I have read the question several times, and I don't get it because I don't follow your train of thought. For example, "Next, consider the first condition assume that $\beta=0$. Hence .. ", doesn't make any sense. Secondly, you can choose $\beta =0$ but the proof still needs to hold for any value that is greater or equal to 0. It seems the proof is written with only $\beta =0$ in mind.

Comment: no. you are completely wrong. The proof is correct for every polynomial. Only to show this one uses the conditions 1 and 2. when one uses these two conditions, one can chose the parameters as he/she wishes.

Comment: I can't follow your english for the above comment.

Comment: @lars btw this question is a trivial one. I mean it doesnt need a proofs at all. I wrote one of the simplest proof one could ever write in terms of understandability. I just wanted to help you thats all.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm more lost than ever. I don't follow your train of thought. I don't see how the conclusions follow from the premises. It's not entirely clear what the premises are at times to me.

Comment: yes that is the problem. it is not clear to you but I am sure it is very clear for almost everyone who understands basic math. So I am sorry, I cannot help you more than this. Good luck.

Comment: Btw, your comments about $k_3 = k_1 * k_2 ...$. What are you trying to explain? Obviously, I don't understand it because I can't tell what you are referring to?

Comment: I am telling you that if you apply the second condition written in your question, you can get any degree of a variable! For example $k_1^2*k_2$. If $k_1=k_2$ then $k^3$ is also a valid kernel. Similarly, if you iteratively apply this condition you can get any power of $k$ as a valid kernel. Understand?

Comment: But what question are you trying to answer with that comment? I don't understand how your comment is relevant to the question or my questions.